# Error with Assert statement in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, questasim

I have the following assert statement in a for loop, which is within a generate block:

```
34   assert ((a[j] == 1'b1) || (a[j] == 1'b0))
35   else $error("Input 'a[" + j + "]' is not a digital logic value");
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

> Error: *file*(34): near "(": syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting property

From what I can see, I'm not missing any parentheses in the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't telling you that you're missing any parentheses; it's telling you that it isn't expecting a parenthesis at all in that spot.

You didn't provide any context, but if your `assert` is outside a procedural block (`initial` or `always`), then a property name must appear between the `assert` and the `(`. This is known as an "concurrent assert".

The other type (the syntax you used) is an "immediate assert", and can only appear inside a procedural block.

Additional details [here](https://www.design-reuse.com/articles/10907/using-systemverilog-assertions-in-rtl-code.html).

Comment: I changed my generate block to be an always block. That has fixed the problem. Thanks!